# Laravel 8: How to show result from related tables at blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project and in this project, I have created two tables.

One of them is named `users` which simply contains user information of the website and the other one is `tags` which contains some hashtags that users can choose from them.

I also created another table named `tag_user` that can store the `tag_id` and `user_id` like this image:

[image: capture]

Then at the Model `User`, I added this:

```
public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
```

And at the Model `Tag`:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

Now I want to show `name` of each tags that `Auth::user()` has been selected.

So in order to do that, I coded this:

```
<h2 class="text-primary">{{ Auth::user()->tags() }}</h2>
```

But this one returns `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given` error.

So my question is, how can I properly show this result at blade?

I really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

And also here is the screenshot of table `tags`, if you would like to see:

[image: capture 2]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try Auth::user->tags and remember without () curly brackets?

Comment: @i89human It is showing this: `id":1,"name":"php","label":"","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"pivot":{"user_id":4,"tag_id":1}},{"id":2,"name":"javascript","label":"","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"pivot":`

Comment: @i89human How to properly show tag names

Comment: i gave detailed reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use tags() with curly braces. Auth::user()->tags will be fine. without curly braces.

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->tags as $tag)

<p>
{{ $tag->name. ',' }}
</p>

@endforeach
```

Tags() will tell you what kind of relationship you are calling. that is used to build queries over that relationship. But if you will user Auth::user()->tags then it will show real data. Remember that. Never use curly braces with laravel relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I think looking for some thing like this,

```
<h2 class="text-primary">@foreach(Auth::user()->tags as $tag)
{{ $tag->name. ',' }}

@endforeach</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

The relationship in user model is wrong, it must be has many.
The user Has many tags, and the tags belongs to users.

also the tags ( belongs to user ), not belong to many.

in tags :

```
  public function user()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
```

in User model :

```
  public function tags()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(Tag::class);
   }
```

Comment: Can you tell me what should I do have to add at Models instead?

Comment: he does not need to change relationships or anything. he is using tags() with braces. he need to use Auth::user()->tags

Comment: that's also correct, but he also need to modify the relationship because it is wrong.

Comment: @AhmedAli why? i guess it is simply many to many relationship.